# Contraction of a differential equation and its mapping

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider a differential equation $\frac{dx}{dt}(t) = 2cos(tx^2(t))$ with initial condition x(0) =1. Check that the solutions can be found as fixed points of the map such that

$f(t) : t \in [0,T]) \to ( 1 + \int_0^t 2cos(sf^2(s)) ds : t \in [0,T] )$

which i have done, but now i have been asked to find on what interval $[0,T]$ can you guarantee this map is a contraction in $(C[0,T],||.||_\infty) $

Answer (score 0):

Read (or re-read) the proof of the [Picard–Lindelöf theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem). You'll see the following condition: $$T\le \min(b/M,1/L)\tag{1}$$ where

- $M$ is the maximum of the righthand side $f(x,t)=2\cos(t x^2)$ on the rectangle $[0,T]\times [1-b,1+b]$,
- $L$ is its Lipschitz constant of $f$ with respect to $x$, on the same rectangle.

Note that you get to choose $b$, but there is a trade-off: small $b$ will limit $T$ directly, while large $b$ will result in large $L$ or $M$, which also limits $T$. 
I don't know how much finesse is expected of you here. I would estimate $L$ by the partial $f_x$, roughly: $L\le 2t\sup |2x|\le 4T(1+b)$. And of course $M\le 2$ works. Now if I choose $b$ and $T$ so that 
$$T=\frac{b}{2} = \frac{1}{4T(1+b)}$$ then (1) is satisfied. This is a cubic equation for $T$ with the root $T\approx 0.377$. I would say that $T=1/3$ works and leave it at that.